# Error trying to install Label-Maker Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install label-maker on python in windows 10 using python 3 in a Jupyter Notebook of Anaconda Navigator.
But I'm getting this error

`!pip install label-maker`

```
errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Yeison\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1c8s62ql\pyproj\`

I install "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, but didn't work.

I've been searching for answer here, but no one solved this. I'm new on python.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post any error messages while using VS, we need those to help.

Comment: What is "VS"? Sorry, I'm new here. Thanks

Comment: My fault.  I meant Visual C++ 14.0.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but if you use Anaconda as your distribution, you may rather invoke `conda install label-maker`

Comment: Depending on the installation settings, the C++ compiler of Visual Studio might not be in the path and its environment variables may be missing too. `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin` contains a batch file `vcvars32.bat`, which you can use from a command prompt and get the variables set. Running it from Jupyter probably will not work, instead, you could try the "Open Terminal" option in Anaconda Navigator (when picking an environment), and call this batch file and then the issue pip commands from there.